# Two sites using different userdata but the same session domain in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, dns

I'm using Codeigniter. I have 2 sites, they look like that:

http://example.com/system/

http://example.com/system2/

These two systems have different userdata. In first site, I haven't set a parameter `class`, but in the second I've set it. When user first open `http://example.com/system/` and then open 
`http://example.com/system2/` it's showing error message: `undefined index class`. Both sites in session domain is: `example.com`. 
How to make to have different session? Maybe I have to set different domain in session? I haven't set it before, how to do that?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774130/access-subdomain-session-from-main-domain/30774191#30774191) hope you are looking for ths

Comment: In my case, it should be something like this? In first system: $config['cookie_prefix'] = "example.com/system_";
$config['cookie_domain'] = "example.com/system"; In second: $config['cookie_prefix'] = "example.com/system2_";
$config['cookie_domain'] = "example.com/system2";

Comment: In the above way, I coulnd't log in. Now I changed prefix. For the first site it is: $config['cookie_prefix'] = "system_"; for the second-$config['cookie_prefix'] = "system2_"; And when I have logged in the first and enter the second, it redirects me to log in. But when I first open second and then first , I'm still logged. How to redirect to log in?

Comment: did you find an answer for this ?

Comment: No, I haven't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

On each system use database and change the database name as well as the cookie name in config.php

```
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'system_x_session';
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'system_x_cookie';
```

where **x** is your system number or you can name it any name

don't forget to create the two tables in your database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `system_x_session` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

this will make your sessions independent from each other and you can check their content with phpmyadmin and the likes

hope that helps

Comment: I don't have such kind of table in database. I don't save session in database. What should I do?

Comment: create them with the 2nd code in the answer just change x to 1 and 2, here is the ci doc https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html , scroll to Saving Session Data to a Database to understand how to use tables to store session data , but in your case you need to create 2 tables one for each system

Comment: Is there another method without changing database?

Comment: probably , but I'm used to use database for that, maybe someone else knows how to do it without database, but, using database is really a good thing, if your application grows and say you host it on several servers (virtual or dedicated), then each server will have its own session,that's an issue, using database allows you to centralize data, ,avoid any conflict, and scale your solution, and even using a load balancer for speeding up data flow .

Comment: Thanks, if someone else knows how to do that without database :)