# CodeIgniter 3 session regenerated after login in Firefox

Tags: codeigniter, session, redirect, codeigniter-3

After login, I set session with user id and some information. It works very well on Google Chrome.
But it is redirect to login page after login on Firefox. I don't know what is the problem. Furthermore, the strange issue is this is working well on my local server like 127.0.0.4. This redirect issue is occurred on live server(hostinger) and only on Firefox.

Here is my config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'eq_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE; // JFRH
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'eq_sessions'; // JFRH
// $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'public/sess';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

And this function is customized library for authentication.

```
public function sess_validate($redi = FALSE, $sess_upda = FALSE) {
      $CI =& get_instance();
      if ($CI->session->userdata('sess_id')) {
         //Preguntar si la variable de sesión 'usua' existe o si se requiere
         //que los datos de la misma sean actualizados
         if ((!$CI->session->userdata('usua')) || ($sess_upda == TRUE)) {
            $this->__sess_update();
         }
         return TRUE; 
      } else {         
         if (!$redi) {
            return FALSE;
         } else {
            print "<script> window.location.href = '".  base_url('auth')."'; </script>";
         }
      }
   }
```

I set session data in my Auth Controller like this.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('sess_id', $usua->id_usu);
$this->session->set_userdata('sess_na', $usua->nom_usu . " " . $usua->ape_usu);
$this->session->set_userdata('sess_log', $usua->log_usu);
```

I have tested with changed session path.

Comment: what codeigniter 3 version you are using in localhost and what version in production?  Also please let us know the php version you have on localhost and on production

Comment: CI version is 3.1.5 and PHP version is 7.4. Server and localhost are same about this versions.

Comment: ok, there have been some session issues in the earlier CI 3.1. versions, please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48646409/2275490 Upgrade to the latest 3.1.13 which most likely will fix the problem...

Comment: Thanks for your help. but there are another CI project with same version. I am use subdomain for my project. Main domain is working well, but mine isn't I have checked config file and everything is same. Can you please explain what can be a problem?

Comment: switching from domain to subdomain is most likely killing the session, since they are considered as 2 domains, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774130/access-subdomain-session-from-main-domain. You should edit your question explaining the domain/sub-domain issue you mentioned in your last comment

Comment: Subdomain is different project with main domain and don't share the session. I am pretty sure this is not related with version and config. I tried with updated version(3.1.13) and changed config to store session into the database. But this is same like before.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this.
Here are my config.php.

`$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

As you can see, I was set the root like above line.
It works on my local server but server protocol was https when I deploy this on server. It is a cause of this problem.
So I fixed this like this.

```
$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === 0 ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$root = $protocol . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

Now, works fine.